# Slave DNS not acessible from outside network: Bind9 misconfiguration or firewall issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm not sure why I can't access my Slave DNS from outside my network.
I've probably done something wrong while configuring it, but I just can't figure out what.
Can someone give me a little help?
Thank you already.

**pfSense (10.1.1.1):**
Interface: WAN
Protocol: UDP 
Source Addr: *
Source Ports: *
Dest. Address: WAN Address
Dest. Ports: 53
NAT IP: 10.1.1.15
NAT Ports: 53

I can't see anything in my log and my ISP has already opened all UDP ports.

**Slave DNS (10.1.1.15):**
*/etc/named.conf:*

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.1.1.15; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion yes;        
        allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 10.1.1.0/24; };
        allow-recursion-on { 127.0.0.1; 10.1.1.0/24; };

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

         pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
        type forward;
#        forward only;
forwarders { 213.186.33.99; 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
};


zone "domain1.com.br" IN {
        type slave;
        file "bak.domain1.com.br";
        masterfile-format text;
        masters { masterdnsip; };
};

zone "domain2.com.br" IN {
        type slave;
 file "bak.domain2.com.br";
        masterfile-format text;
        masters { masterdnsip; };
};
zone "domain3.com.br" IN {
        type slave;
        file "bak.domain3.com.br";
        masterfile-format text;
        masters { masterdnsip; };
};

zone "re.ver.se.ip.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        file "bak.domain1.com.br-reverso";
        masterfile-format text;
        masters { masterdnsip; };
};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Comment: It's weird to see you define the root zone (".") as type forward instead of just defining forwarders in the `options` part of the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If your WAN address really is 10.1.1.1 which is in a private address range then I really don't see how your nameserver can be reached from the internet unless your ISP provided you with public IP which they MAP to that address (or at least map DNS port 53 from there to you).

Comment: I'm sorry, my WAN address is 192.168.1.3. The 10.1.1.1 is ny LAN address.
I have an external IP which I use to connect to my servers when I'm outside. To connect on them, I just set a NAT rule to redirect ports. In this case, I redirected everything coming from any address on port 53/UDP to my 10.1.1.15 on port 53/UDP, just like any other services I use from outside.

Comment: 192.168.1.3 is still a private address. How is your public IP configured on WAN interface?

Comment: I have a device that authenticates and gets the external address. From it, my firewall gets all the requests via DMZ. From my firewall, I reroute everything on port 53 to 10.1.1.15:53.

Comment: Is your device which has public IP also forwarding port 53 requests to the firewall IP (which should be 192.168.1.3)?

Comment: According to my ISP, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing packet captures, either with **tcpdump** on the pfSense machine and DNS server or by using SPAN ports on your switches and using Wireshark. That way you can see the packets before and after the firewall and verify your NAT rules are working fine. Next, if the traffic also correctly enters your DNS server, you can start checking the configuration of that server.

If you're able to make some packet captures, please share that information with us as well. It will help us analyze the problem as we currently have too little information to work with.